# C# DataGridViewSelectedRowCollectionとDataGridViewRowCollection

Tags: c#, winforms

DataGridViewに表示したデータに対し、選択したレコードを処理するメソッドと
DataGridViewに表示した全てのレコードを処理するメソッドを共通にしたいのですが、
タイトルの二つのCollectionはどちらかにキャストしたりできないでしょうか？
(共通メソッドの引数を同じにできればと考えています。)

最悪、全てのレコードを処理する場合には全て選択させてDataGridViewSelectedRowCollectionを
処理する方法もあるかと思いますが、なんかきれいじゃない気がしまして。。

お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それぞれの値に`.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`を付ければ`IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`型にラップ出来ます。`foreach`のみであればこの型で十分です。

またリストであることが必要なのであれば、`IList`型を引数にするのが良いと思います。この場合コレクションは変換不要ですが、各要素を`DataGridViewRow`にキャストする必要があります。

Comment: 今回は`foreach`を利用して処理するだけでしたので、`.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`を利用させて頂きました。
共通メソッドの引数に`IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`を指定してうまくいきそうです。

Answer (score 2):

LINQを用いてDataGridViewRowの配列に変換すれば良いでしょう。

```
   IList<DataGridViewRow> list = rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()  // DataGridViewRowに変換できた要素のみ通す
    .ToArray();                 // 配列化する。
```

OfTypeと似ているものにCastがありますが、Castは、キャストできない場合に例外がスローされます。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。LINQでできるんですね！